# Show that from any five integers, one can always choose three of these integers such that their sum is divisible by 3.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that from any five integers, one can always choose three of these integers such that their sum is divisible by 3.

I wasn't sure how to solve this problem, can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is a special case with $n = 3$ of a more general theorem of "Given any $2n−1$ integers, there is at least one subset of $n$ integers whose sum is divisible by $n$". The theorem statement & proof is given in [Nine divisible by 9](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol80.pdf). For another specific case, there's [Given any nine numbers, prove there exists a subset of five numbers such that its sum is divisible by $5$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678557/given-any-nine-numbers-prove-there-exists-a-subset-of-five-numbers-such-that-it?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

First we assume it is possible for a set that does not satisfy the conditions to exist, and then we consider all numbers modulo $3$. Note that we cannot have three numbers the same mod 3 as adding them all together would yield a multiple of $3$. But this means that there is at least one number that is $0$, one number that is $1$ and one that is $2$ ($\text{mod }3$), and summing these gives a multiple of three, giving a contradiction.